# How to break Async series on SIGTERM?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js, sigterm

Assume I have the following scenario -

```
async.series(
  [
    function (cbi) {
      students.getAll('student', function (err, response) {
        if (err) {
          logger.error(err);
        }
        cbi(err, response);
      });
    },
    function (cbi) {
      students.deleteAll('student', function (err, response) {
        if (err) {
          logger.error(err);
        }
        cbi(err, response);
      });
    },
    function (cbi) {
      teachers.getAll('teacher', function (err, response) {
        if (err) {
          logger.error(err);
        }
        cbi(err, response);
      });
    },
    function (cbi) {
      teachers.deleteAll('teacher', function (err, response) {
        if (err) {
          logger.error(err);
        }
        cbi(err, response);
      });
    };
  ]
);
```

And I want a graceful cleanup when `SIGTERM` is sent. That is a clean up of all the students or all teachers whichever is in progress when the signal was sent should complete and the next one should not begin.

```
function (cbi) {
  students.getAll('student', function (err, response) {
    if (err || GLOBAL_VAR_SIGTERM === true) {
      logger.error(err);
    }
    cbi(err, response);
  });
}
```

I was thinking that I should set a global variable to keep track of the `SIGTERM` signal.

```
process.on('SIGTERM', function onSigterm () {
  GLOBAL_VAR_SIGTERM = true;
}
```

Is there any better way to break an async series to break a `SIGTERM` signal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @adamrights points out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55876084/3617380), the main problem in your code is you didn't call `cbi(err, response)` with a truthy `err` 1st param, which is essential to stop `async.series` continuing to next task in the queue.

Now your code should work, but you have a repeating pattern in your code that goes:

```
function (cbi) {
  students.getAll('student', function (err, response) {
    // these 3 lines appear in every callback function
    if (GLOBAL_VAR_SIGTERM) err = new Error("SIGTERM: Aborting remaining tasks");
    if (err) logger.error(err);
    cbi(err, response);
    // end of repeat pattern
  });
}
```

Your callback passed to every async task always do the same 3-liner thing. We know the DRY rule, it's always a good idea to extract the repeating pattern into another function to reuse it as much as possible.

So instead of repeatedly declaring anonymous functions, you should declare a *factory function*.

```
function callbackFactory(cbi) {
  return function(err, response) {
    if (GLOBAL_VAR_SIGTERM) err = new Error("SIGTERM: Aborting remaining tasks");   
    if (err) logger.error(err);
    cbi(err, response);
  }
}

// use arrow function to write more concise code
async.series(
  [
    cbi => students.getAll('student', callbackFactory(cbi)),
    cbi => students.deleteAll('student', callbackFactory(cbi)),
    cbi => teachers.getAll('teacher', callbackFactory(cbi)),
    cbi => teachers.deleteAll('teacher', callbackFactory(cbi)),
  ]
);
```

---

### Advance Topic: use decorator to handle cross cutting concern

Let's explore this topic a bit more. Obviously, abort early on receiving `SIGTERM` is a cross cutting concern that should be separated from business logic. Suppose your business logic varies from task to task:

```
async.series(
  [
    cbi => students.getAll('student', (err, response) => {
      if (err) {
        logger.error(err);
        return cbi(err);
      }
      updateStudentCount(response.data.length)  // <- extra work
      cbi(err, response);
    }),
    cbi => teachers.getAll('student', (err, response) => {
      if (err) {
        logger.error(err);
        return cbi(err);
      }
      updateTeacherCount(response.data.length)  // <- different extra work
      cbi(err, response);
    })
  ]
);
```

Because the callback is varying, it can be difficult to be extracted into a factory function like before. From this perspective, we'd better *inject* the abort-early behavior to each task, keep it easy to write normal business logic.

This is where *decorator pattern* comes handy. But global variable isn't the best tool to implement it, we'll use event listener.

The basic interface of the decorator looks like:

```
// `task` will be things like `cbi => students.getAll('student', ... )`
function decorateTaskAbortEarly(task) {
  return (originalCbi) => {
    ...
    task(originalCbi)
  }
}
```

Below is our implementation checklist:

- we're going to call `originalCbi` if we receive `SIGTERM`
- but when we don't receive `SIGTERM`, the `originalCbi` is still callable inside callback of any async task like normal
- if `originalCbi` is ever called once, we should unsubscribe from `SIGTERM` to prevent memory leak

The implementation:

```
function decorateTaskAbortEarly(task) {
  return (originalCbi) => {
    // subscribe to `SIGTERM`
    var listener = () => originalCbi(new Error("SIGTERM: Aborting remaining tasks"));
    process.once('SIGTERM', listener);

    var wrappedCbi = (err, response) => {
      // unsubscribe if `cbi` is called once
      process.off('SIGTERM', listener);
      return originalCbi(err, response);
    };
    // pass `cbi` through to `task`
    task(wrappedCbi);
  }
}

// Usage:
async.series(
  [
    cbi => students.getAll('student', (err, response) => {
      if (err) {
        logger.error(err);
        return cbi(err);
      }
      updateStudentCount(response.data.length)
      cbi(err, response);
    }),
    cbi => teachers.getAll('student', (err, response) => {
      if (err) {
        logger.error(err);
        return cbi(err);
      }
      updateTeacherCount(response.data.length)
      cbi(err, response);
    })
  ].map(decorateTaskAbortEarly)  // <--- nice API
);
```

Comment: The `if (err) logger.error(err);` should simply be placed in the callback of `async.series`, not in each individual callback.

Comment: @Bergi I know, but I just want to keep the irrelevant part as-is, reduce noise so important part gets more highlight.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to respond to the `SIGTERM` event from within the `async.series()` then you are correct, the easiest way would be to track with a global variable.

But you need to set the first parameter (error-first callback) in the `cbi(err, response)` function to `true` in order to break the series.

so:

```
if (err || GLOBAL_VAR_SIGTERM === true) {
  logger.error(err);
}
```

should be more like:

```
if (err) logger.error(err);
if (GLOBAL_VAR_SIGTERM) err = new Error("SIGTERM: Aborting remaining tasks");
// You could just do err = true
// But best practice is to use an Error instance.
```

Then because `cbi(err, response)` will be called with `err` value equal to`true` the remaining tasks will not be run.

Answer (score 1):

I liked the other answers. This is another way to achieve the same. I am using my own example:

```
var async = require('async');
var ifAsync = require('if-async')
var GLOBAL_VAR_SIGTERM = false;

async.series({
    one: ifAsync(notsigterm).then(function (callback) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log('one');
            callback(null, 1);
        }, 1000);
    }),
    two: ifAsync(notsigterm).then(function (callback) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log('two');
            callback(null, 2);
        }, 1000);
    }),
    three: ifAsync(notsigterm).then(function (callback) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log('three');
            callback(null, 3);
        }, 1000);
    }),
    four: ifAsync(notsigterm).then(function (callback) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log('four');
            callback(null, 4);
        }, 1000);
    }),
}, function (err, results) {
    if (err) {
        //Handle the error in some way. Here we simply throw it
        //Other options: pass it on to an outer callback, log it etc.
        throw err;
    }
    console.log('Results are ' + JSON.stringify(results));
});

process.on('SIGTERM', function onSigterm () {
    console.log('SIGTERM caught');

  GLOBAL_VAR_SIGTERM = true;
});

function notsigterm(callback) {
    if (!GLOBAL_VAR_SIGTERM) return callback(null, true)
    else return callback(null, false)
}
```

I am using a package called `ifAsync` which allows you to use a predicate `notsigterm` to decide if a callback should be invoked or not. If `notsigterm` returns true then the callback will be invoked else it will be skipped. This is similar answer to others but somehow I find this cleaner. Let me know if you have questions.